# Bashert-Steipler

Tags: sources-mekorot, shidduchim, steipler

I recall hearing in the name of the Steipler that the only time we can know that a shidduch is actually the one that was נגזר עליו מ' יום קודם יצירת הולד is if the shidduch is from 2 separate cities in a way that בדרך הטבע these 2 people shouldn't have met.

Does anyone know where this can be found?

Comment: I have never heard this before, but seemingly this would not apply today. In the age of the internet, and shadchanim connecting globally, its perfectly normal and within derech hateva for people to met and marry from 2 distant cities.

Comment: I don't think that's true, I don't think the Steipler ever said that.